# Implement a general switch case

Tags: java, switch-statement

I want to create a general switch case statement in Java.
I'm making a program and at some point I have to make 32 different cases for the switch statement like: `case 0 : , case 1 : , .... case 31 :`. And then in every case I have to write some lines of code. Is there any way to implement a general switch case statement so that I don't have to write 32 separate cases?

For example:

```
switch(n){
case k :
.....
{
```

How can I implement this in java? Is it possible?

Comment: What are the differences between the code in each case?

Comment: @AshBurlaczenko in each case i have to write 2 lines and their variables depend on the case...so at case 0 the variable that im going to use later is 0*L(l is the variable which value i want , and firstly its L=8)...then case 1 is 1*L ...case 2 : 2*L and so on

Comment: From your description it seems like you can replace `case` with `n * L` expression...

Comment: The switch won't work for you if you don't want to write each case since the variable changes. fge answer could be a way to do what you want.

Comment: @TomaszNurkiewicz yes but as i said before each case has 2  lines of code ..i mean that i have another variable that depends on k except L ..the other variable is k*L-1 .

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau im a beginner in java and i didn't quite get what you mean

Comment: @Joni From what I get of your question, using a switch isn't what you're looking for. fge's answer might be a solution that would fits your needs. It seems the variable you want to use is different for each case rather than having a variable's value change, if that's your situation, all cases using different variables need to be written.

Answer (score 5):

Why not just use a `default` branch:

```
switch (n) {
  // cases for which you need custom behavior...
  default:
    // use n for the general case
}
```

Comment: cause at every case i have a variable depending on the case number .. case 0 : 0*L case 1 : 1*L and so on

Comment: @Joni If that's literally the issue then write `n*L`. Otherwise please explain better.

Comment: Yup.  This actually sounds like you shouldn't use a `switch` at all -- you should just compute `n * L` in your code.

Comment: @PaulBellora i have also another variable inside each case : L1 = k*L-1...i have to write 32 different cases,i want to know is theres a way to write the switch with only one  case: k .but a cant use k since its not a constant cause it has to take values from 0 till 31

Comment: @Joni: So what if you need to compute `k * L - 1`?  Just write `k * L - 1`.  None of the reasons you've explained are valid reasons to need a `switch` statement at all.  If you actually showed us the real code you're trying to write, we could provide you with the real code that's simpler.

Comment: @LouisWasserman  i have also another variable inside each case : L1 = k*L-1...i have to write 32 different cases,i want to know is theres a way to write the switch with only one  case: k .but a cant use k since its not a constant cause it has to take values from 0 till 31

Comment: @Joni Wait, did you just copy/paste the same comment again? I'm leaving.

Comment: switch (n)
        
   case 0:
    start = 0*Line;
    finish = 1*Line-1;
    break; ....so on 
   case 28:
    start = 28*Line;
    finish = 29*Line-1;
    break;
   case 29:
    start = 29*Line;
    finish = 30*Line-1;
    break;
   case 30:
    start = 30*Line;
    finish = 31*Line-1;
    break;
   case 31:
    start = 31*Line;
    finish = 32*Line-1;
    break;

Comment: That entire `switch` statement can be replaced by two lines: `start = n * Line; finish = (n + 1) * Line - 1;`  That's it.  There's no reason to be using a `switch` statement here.

Comment: @LouisWasserman thank you ...just as i looked at the code again that seems to be right . Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You can use an enum. For instance, here is an enum which matches digits' names with their integer values:

```
enum MyDigit
{
    ZERO(0),
    ONE(1),
    TWO(2),
    // etc
    NINE(9);

    private final int intValue;

    MyDigit(int intValue)
    {
        this.intValue = intValue;
    }

    public int intValue()
    {
        return intValue;
    }
}
```

Enums are very flexible. For instance, you could also build a reverse map of all values and use a static lookup method to get the wanted value of the enum.

(yes, some people will say that the integer value is redundant here since I can use `values()`/`ordinal()`, but that is for illustration)

Answer (score 0):

When you see a switch statement of 32 cases and one that potentially has to be augmented often, it usually signals a [code or design "smell"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_smell).  Chances are you'd have to replicated this switch structure in multiple places of your code and then you'll end with high maintenance costs and a brittle code that violates the [Open/closed Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) and the [Single Responsibility Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle) (as a single change in requirements may force you to chance code in multiple locations).

A solution to this problem is decomposition of your code into multiple classes to take advantage of [polymorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polymorphism_in_object-oriented_programming).  When you work on your decomposition, you have to be thinking in terms of what [Design Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_design_pattern) would provide you with the most appropriate replacement for your switch statement.  Some potential candidates (since I don't know the nature of your code) are: [Command](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), [Strategy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strategy_pattern), [Visitor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern); but there are others as well.

Comment: actually my code has some switch statements, with 32 cases , 16 cases , 8 cases and 4 ..thats why i want to use a general switch so that to save a lot of space and also not to get lost in the code

Comment: without knowing the innards of your code, my comment still stands.  The way to abstract a switch statement is with polimorphism.

Answer (score 0):

> in each case i have to write 2 lines and their variables depend on the case...so at case 0 the variable that im going to use later is 0*L(l is the variable which value i want , and firstly its L=8)...then case 1 is 1*L ...case 2 : 2*L and so on

well, check if your input number is a number between 0 and 32, then just do n*L

```
int result = 0;
if(n>=0&&n<32){
    result=n*L;
}else{
    System.err.println("wrong number");
    //or do whatever you have to
}
```